# Xamarin Studio - Save Failed. Attempted to performed an unauthorized operation

Tags: c#, macos, save, filesystems, xamarin-studio

I am using xamarin studio in MAC PC.
When I am trying to add reference or change the property of the file it throw the error:

[image]
Please send me solution

Comment: I would guess there is some file permission problem on the file being saved. What is in the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlocked all files and folder of the project solved problem